# What ZSH command allows you to use shortcuts like !!, !$, etc, without hitting space/enter first?

Tags: zsh

So by default, when I use Zsh for the first time shortcuts like `!!` (for previous command), `!$` (for last argument of previous command), `!v` (for last command starting with `v`), and so on, work like they do in Bash, ie I could do:

```bash
rm -rf /
sudo !!
```

(No trailing whitespace at the end of those two lines except for just hitting enter after the last character)

for instance. However I have a zshrc with oh-my-zsh and a couple of plugins that come with OMZ, as well as using the powerline10k theme, and whenever I copy my config to a new machine, after copying it over, it now works where you need to either hit enter or space in order to "expand" the shortcut, e.g. for the above example, again with no trailing whitespace just hitting enter at the end of the line, it would become three commands:

```bash
rm -rf /
sudo !!
sudo rm -rf /
```

You then have to hit enter again on the third line for the command to actually execute.

Or in just two lines, you would type:

```bash
rm -rf /
sudo !!
```

(no trailing whitespace)

And then when you type:

```bash
rm -rf /
sudo !!<SPACE>
```

(`<SPACE>` not being literal, being a representation of a space character at the end of the line)

It automatically expands to:

```bash
rm -rf /
sudo rm -rf /<SPACE><your cursor is here>
```

I assume this is a safety feature so you can review what your shortcut expands to before hitting enter, but honestly when this happens I just double-tap enter anyway as a reflexive thing, so it's not really adding extra security for me.

My question is: does anyone know what setting in the zshrc (or elsewhere) causes this behaviour, and how can I disable it so I can just use these shortcuts the way they work in default out-of-the-box Zsh?

(I tried to look this up, however I don't know what these shortcuts are called, and looking things up like `zsh enable !! shortcut` `zsh enable "!!" shortcut` etc just does not give you helpful results)

Comment: Is the [histverify](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HISTVERIFY) option set the same in both cases?

Comment: @steeldriver Not set in both zshrcs. Tried setting it to false but it doesn't seem to change the behaviour